# Saving part of a string in another string but keeping the original string. C++

Tags: c++, string

```
string2 = string1.erase(f, 2);
```

I'm trying to assign a value to string 2 based on a part of string1 that has to be erased without actually affecting string1.

It seems that the .erase() member function changes string1 first before assigning string 2 its value.

For example if

```
string1 = "A4";
f = 0;
```

string2 should be set to "" and string1 remains "A4"

and if

```
string1 = "A4B4C1"
f = 2
```

string2 should be set to "A4C1" and string1 remains "A4B4C1"

Comment: So what is the problem, what have you tried?

Comment: So copy string1 into string2 first, and then modify it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy `string1` into `string2`, then modify the latter:

```
string2 = string1;
string2.erase(f, 2);
```

Comment: How did I not think of this.. Thank you!